# Execute SQL from batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I'm new to batch files scripting.

All I want is creating a batch file that calling SQL file and store results in text file .

Can anyone help me, your help is highly appreciated,

This is the first time I need to create such files.

Comment: Please make your question more explicit: What database are you using? SQL Server (Version)? MySQL? Oracle? If you're using SQL Server, have you read the documentation for SQLCMD (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165702(v=SQL.105).aspx)?

Comment: am sorry for that, I use Oracle 10g database

Answer (score 8, accepted):

using a batch file:

save and run this:

```
@echo off
sqlplus -s -l user/pass@yourdb @yoursql.sql>your_log.log
```

p.s. be sure to have the last line of your sql script as `exit;` or the batch file will hang.

Comment: Thanks Dazzal for help 
this was extremely helpful, but there is still a problem because the log file empty even though I had tried running the query on TOAD and it returned results. 

below is the script : 

@echo off
sqlplus -s -l DBUserName/dbPassword@DBName @SQLFile.sql>ResultFile.txt

Comment: @Manaysah if you log into sqlplus then and run that script without the DOS batch, does it output anything? if its outputting data with dbms_output, then make sure your script has `set serveroutput on size 1000000` at the top

Comment: Dazzal,  thanks 
the problem were in SQL file, the sql should be included in double quotation. 
i included the "" characters but another problem raised, is the "@" charcter. replacing the "@" with "start" solved the issue but the results were seemingly irrelevant. 
 the results file look like this "SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production

Copyright (c) 1982, 2010, Oracle.  All rights reserved. ....."

Comment: The problem solved 
the issue were in putting the query inside double quotation the issue resolved by replacing it by semicolon (;)

Comment: @DazzaL thanks for that, but even with the `exit;`  the batch file is still hanging... any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

```
sqlcmd -S sqlservername -i yoursqlfile.sql -U username -P password -o outputfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a more advanced launcher, try it out (you can find the latest version at http://www.unix.com/windows-and-dos-issues-and-discussions/256021-windowss-batch-launcher-oracle-sql-linux-sh-scripts-available-here.html)

Here's the code anyway:

launcher.cmd

```
@ECHO OFF

rem Script Launcher by Fr3dY v1.4
rem ##############################
rem Version History:
rem 1.4 - Misc. fixes
rem 1.3 - Merged with 'server launcher', now accepts both SQL and SHELL SCRIPTS
rem 1.2 - Interactive prompt to show the file on screen
rem 1.1 - No need to add 'quit;' or 'exit;' in the .sql file anymore
rem       Fixed sqlplus waiting for username/password if the first attempt was unsuccessful
rem       Log file is generated automatically, including date and time in name
rem       Misc. fixes
rem 1.0 - Initial Version

:MAIN
::Path of PLINK
set PLINK="C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\plink.exe"
::List with TNS NAMES
set dbservers=launcher-databases.txt
::List with LINUX SERVERS
set linuxservers=launcher-servers.txt

set dt=%DATE:~6,4%_%DATE:~3,2%_%DATE:~0,2%__%TIME:~0,2%_%TIME:~3,2%_%TIME:~6,2%
set dt=%dt: =0%

echo Choose launcher mode:
echo 1) Database scripts (.sql files)
echo 2) Shell scripts (.sh files)
set /p launchermode="Insert value: "
echo.

if %launchermode%==1 (
  set extension=sql
  set servers=%dbservers%
  set mode=DB
) else (
    if %launchermode%==2 (
      set extension=sh
      set servers=%linuxservers%
      set mode=OS
    ) else (echo "Incorrect value, exiting..." & goto :END)
)    

if exist %servers% (
  goto :LISTFILES
) else echo FILE %servers% NOT FOUND, ABORTING & goto :END


:LISTFILES
echo Listing *.%extension% files...
echo.
dir /b *.%extension%
echo.

set /p file=Name of the file to be launched (without extension)? 

if exist %file%.%extension% (
  goto :CONFIRMSHOW
) else echo FILE %file%.%extension% NOT FOUND, ABORTING & goto :END


:CONFIRMSHOW
echo.
set /p confirm=Show the script %file%.%extension% on screen now? 
if %confirm%==y (
  goto :SHOWSCRIPT
  ) else goto :CONFIRMEXEC
echo.

:SHOWSCRIPT
echo.
echo Content of %file%.%extension%
echo ######################
type %file%.%extension%
echo.
echo ######################
echo.

:CONFIRMEXEC
set /p confirm=Are you sure you want to execute this script? 
if %confirm%==y (
  set /p user=%mode% username?  
  goto :HInput
  ) else echo ABORTED & goto :END
echo.
echo Output saved to %file%_%dt%.log
echo.
Goto :END

:HInput
::Hidden.cmd
::Tom Lavedas, 02/05/2013, 02/20/2013
::Carlos, 02/22/2013
::https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.msdos.batch.nt/f7mb_f99lYI
::Version 3.0     
SetLocal DisableDelayedExpansion
echo.
Echo Enter password:
Set "Line="
Rem Save 0x08 character in BS variable
For /F %%# In (
'"Prompt;$H&For %%# in (1) Do Rem"'
) Do Set "BS=%%#"

:HILoop
Set "Key="
For /F "delims=" %%# In (
'Xcopy /L /W "%~f0" "%~f0" 2^>Nul'
) Do If Not Defined Key Set "Key=%%#"
Set "Key=%Key:~-1%"
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
If Not Defined Key echo. & Goto :HIEnd
If %BS%==^%Key% (Set /P "=%BS% %BS%" <Nul
Set "Key="
If Defined Line Set "Line=!Line:~0,-1!"
) Else Set /P "=*" <Nul
If Not Defined Line (EndLocal &Set "Line=%Key%"
) Else For /F delims^=^ eol^= %%# In (
"!Line!") Do EndLocal &Set "Line=%%#%Key%"
Goto :HILoop

:HIEnd
if %launchermode%==1 (
  goto :EXECDB
) else goto :EXECLINUX

:EXECDB
FOR /f %%A IN (%servers%) DO CALL ECHO DATABASE: %%A & ECHO DATABASE: %%A >> %file%_%dt%.log & sqlplus -S -L %user%/!Line!@%%A < %file%.%extension% >> %file%_%dt%.log
goto :END

:EXECLINUX
FOR /f %%A IN (%servers%) DO CALL ECHO SERVER: %%A & ECHO SERVER: %%A >> %file%_%dt%.log & echo y | %PLINK% %user%@%%A -pw !Line! "exit" & %PLINK% %user%@%%A -pw !Line! -batch -m %file%.%extension% >> %file%_%dt%.log & echo. >> %file%_%dt%.log
goto :END

:END
pause
```