# Create batch file to run sql

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file, command-line, sqlplus

I'm trying to create a batch file to run a sql query (which then spools the result).

However, at the moment nothing happens, I just get usage info about sqlplus in the cmd window.  Here is my batch code:

```
SQLPLUS login/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=<url>)(Port=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<sid>)))@C:\Users\Documents\SQL\test2.sql

pause
```

and here is my test2.sql file:

```
spool C:\Users\Documents\Testing.csv

select *
from test;

spool off;
exit;
```

Please help - what am I doing wrong?  (I'm very new to this so please answer/ask/ridicule in simple terms so I can understand)

Comment: Should have said - I'm using windows & oracle.

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation for the proper format of SQLPlus command lines?

Comment: I've basically read the whole internet - hence this question.  The sql works if I put it directly into the command window after connecting to the db.  I've tried various things and this (according to posters on other questions) should work - but it doesn't.  I think maybe because the db is hosted online?  If it's something obvious I'm doing wrong please let me know :)

Comment: You've *read the whole internet*? That's impressive. You shouldn't need our help, then. Does the *whole internet* include http://stackoverflow.com/q/14294068/62576?

Comment: I'm beginning to think you don't know the answer either...  (also - yes I did read that and it didn't work)

Comment: I'm beginning to think you're being rude. Your question provides no information about the parameters you're passing, you show no evidence of doing any research (other than *read the whole internet*), there's no information about your database or it's configuration, and when I provide a link that specifically shows an example command that works you dismiss it.

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude - I've stated I'm very new to this and I've tried searching for an answer before asking for help.  You've come on here to mock me, which is definitely rude.  I don't know what parameters you might need to answer this - this is literally the first time I have used the command prompt.  I've seen the link you provided - I had already tried the suggestion there and it didn't help me.  Oh, and you might want to read this: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/hyperbole

Comment: I haven't mocked anything, other than your statement that you've *read the whole internet* (which is simply ludicrous). The documentation for SQLPlus explains **exactly** what is expected on the command line, and rather than reading it (as I suggested in my first comment) you claim to have *read the whole internet*. http://www.dbasupport.com/forums/showthread.php?10587-how-to-create-a-batch-file-to-invoke-sqlplus-and-run-procedure

Comment: @KenWhite I think 'I have read the whole internet' was meant by OP as a Hyperbole

Comment: @RobertMerkwürdigeliebe: Possibly, but the proper response to *Have you read the documentation?* is not *I read the whole internet*, hyperbole or not. Do you have any idea how many thousands of homework questions have been closed here because they say something like *My assignment is ... I've tried to solve it, and I've read the whole internet, but I can't do it. Can you give me the code?*? When you're asking someone for free help to solve your problem, and they ask for more details, it's appropriate to provide an answer rather than hyperbole.

Comment: @KenWhite I have been on Usenet groups and SO for more than 15 years. I know what you are talking about. But on the other hand: I have seen a lot of grumpy responses of experienced programmers who forgot how it feels to be a newbee lost in an overload of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's something obvious you're doing wrong. You need a space between the end of the connect string and the `@` with the script file name:

```
SQLPLUS login/password@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=<url>)(Port=<port>))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=<sid>))) @C:\Users\Documents\SQL\test2.sql
```

The `<url>` reference is odd here; hopefully that is actually hostname, fully-qualified hostname (that can be resolved), or an IP addrss.

However, I'd suggest you use a TNS alias so you can shorten the command line, putting all that information in a `tnsnames.ora` file instead; or if you know the service name (which might be the same as the SID) use the easy connect syntax:

```
SQLPLUS -l -s login/password@//<hostname>:<port>/<service_name> @C:\Users\Documents\SQL\test2.sql
```

I've also thrown in the -s flag to suppress the banner, and the -l flag so it stops if the credentials or connect string are wrong. Your original  ersion would have tried to use the script contents to log in after the initial failure, producing even more confusing output.