# How to connect to Oracle DB using batch file

Tags: windows, oracle, batch-file

I am automating a process where I have to connect to Oracle database and run a script automatically.

Can somebody help me in achieving this.

I have written a script but when I am executing the below scripts it's not returning any output.

Code :

```
@echo off
set user_name=<username>
set password=<password>
set net_service_name= <tns_name>

echo exit | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name% @f:\test.sql 

pause
```

I am using Oracle 11g. I am connecting to database of a specific region.

Also, I need to connect to database as an admin user.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Execute SQL from batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14294068/execute-sql-from-batch-file)

Comment: I tried but it's not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is in the space in net_service_name. `"-S"` is silent mode for sqlplus. For diagnostics, remove this key and add `rem @echo off`.

For example 1. The space in net_service_name.

```
   rem @echo off
    set user_name=scott
    set password=tiger
    set net_service_name= esmd

    echo exit | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name%  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
    pause
```

output:

```
 C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>echo exit   | sqlplus -s scott/tiger@ esmd  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
    Usage: SQLPLUS [ [<option>] [<logon>] [<start>] ]
    where <option> ::= -H | -V | [ [-L] [-M <o>] [-R <n>] [-S] ]
          <logon>  ::= <username>[/<password>][@<connect_string>] | / | /NOLOG
          <start>  ::= @<URI>|<filename>[.<ext>] [<parameter> ...]
            "-H" displays the SQL*Plus version banner and usage syntax
            "-V" displays the SQL*Plus version banner
            "-L" attempts log on just once
            "-M <o>" uses HTML markup options <o>
            "-R <n>" uses restricted mode <n>
            "-S" uses silent mode

    C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>pause
```

For example 2.

```
 rem @echo off
  set user_name=scott
  set password=tiger
  set net_service_name=esmd

  echo exit | sqlplus -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name%  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
  pause
```

output:

```
C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>echo exit   | sqlplus -s scott/tiger@esmd  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql

SYSDATE
--------
24.01.19

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>pause
```

For example 3. Connect as sysdba.

```
rem @echo off
set user_name=sys
set password=manager
set net_service_name=esmd as sysdba
echo exit | C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sqlplus.exe -s %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name%  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
pause
```

output:

```
C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>echo exit   | C:\oracle\instantclient_11_2\sqlplus.exe -s sys/manageresmd@esmd as sysdba  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql

SYSDATE
--------
24.01.19


C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>pause
```

For example 4. Connect as sysdba.

```
rem @echo off
set user_name=sys
set password=manager
set net_service_name=esmd as sysdba
rem
(
echo  conn %user_name%/%password%@%net_service_name%
echo  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
echo exit
)| sqlplus -s  /nolog
pause
```

output:

```
    C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>(
    echo  conn sys/manageresmd@esmd as sysdba
     echo  @C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql\sqltest.sql
     echo exit
    )  | sqlplus -s  /nolog
    Connected.

    SYSDATE
    --------
    24.01.19

    Elapsed: 00:00:00.00

For example sqltest.sql.

    C:\upwork\stackoverflow\bat_sql>more sqltest.sql
    select sysdate from dual;
```