# Query to count the number of rows in each table and extract a txt file using SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, count, oracle-sqldeveloper, rows

I'm new to using the oracle database and advanced query concepts and even PL / SQL.

I'm trying to create a query where I can see the number of rows in each table in my database and write them in a txt file. The goal is to have a kind of history of how this database is updating every day.

Until then I proceeded using this code below, which works correctly.

```
spool C:\Logs\LOGs.txt
select
   table_name,
   to_number(
   extractvalue(
      xmltype(
         dbms_xmlgen.getxml('select count(*) c from '||table_name))
    ,'/ROWSET/ROW/C')) count
from 
   user_tables
order by 
   table_name;

spool off;
```

Now I am facing two new challenges:

1 - I can't schedule this query correctly in SQL Developer because they only accept procedures and not queries or I can't find a way to schedule this query to run, for example, in task scheduler on windows.

2 - I wanted a way to write the progressive history of the database in the txt file, this query of mine only writes about the current day. I thought of a solution where the name of the file would change according to the date, that way I wouldn't replace the file but I still couldn't.

I appreciate everyone's attention and availability

Comment: Don't manually count rows, use the table stats. Cheaper, still allows for trending.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap the query in a procedure and schedule that, but spool is a client command, so you would need to use `utl_file` to write to a file on the server instead.

You could, instead, save this as a script and write a batch file that runs it through SQL*Plus or SQLcl instead of SQL Developer; and then use Windows scheduling to run that batch file.

By default spool will overwrite an existing file, but you can add `append` to change the behaviour, as described [in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve043.htm#sthref2314):

```
spool C:\Logs\LOGs.txt append
```

Having data in one file might be confusing though, even if you include the current date as another column in your query. You could change the file name each day instead.

Another option is to write the counts to a logging table within the database, which you could then query and compare easily. The insert - using your existing query plus a date - could then easily be wrapped in a procedure, and that procedure can be scheduled.

Comment: Thank you very much your answer will help me a lot, could you suggest me somewhere where I can get technical instructions regarding the creation of this batch file that runs .sql using SQL * Plus?  I believe it should involve adding permissions, user and passwords to access my schema within SQL and I didn't think much about it in a quick search.

Comment: With regard to getting the txt file confused with the dates, I totally agree. Probably the solution to create a table that writes this result would be much better.

However, the person who will make use of this kind of "history/ report" does not know how to use the interface of a sql developer.

Thank you again

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295574/266304) is a very basic batch script.